# Deep mapping in Racket

Tags: mapping, racket

I am trying to write a deep map code in Racket. Basically, it' supposed to take a function fn and list lst, and applies fn (recursively) to every element of lst, returning a list of the same "shape" as the original. lst does not need to be a proper list, and the behavior of deep-map is unlike map, in that the latter will not recursively apply its argument function.

So far what I have is:

```
(define (deep-map fn lst)
  (let rmap ([el (car lst)]
             [acc '()])
    (if (empty? lst)
        acc
        (if (empty? el)
            (rmap (car (cdr lst)) acc)
            (if (list? el)
                (rmap (car (cdr lst)) (cons (map fn el) acc))
                (if (pair? el)
                    (rmap (car (cdr lst)) (cons (cons (fn car el) (fn cdr el)) acc))
                    (rmap (car (cdr lst)) (cons (fn el) acc))))))))
```

I tried so many ways of solving this problem and I keep running into problems. Can anyone give me some guidance on what I should change.
Thank you!

Comment: What problems do you run into?

Comment: One could proceed step-by-step: (1) write `map` (standard natural recursion template), use [Check Forms](https://docs.racket-lang.org/test-engine/index.html#%28mod-path._test-engine%2Fracket-tests%29): `(check-expect (deep-map add1 '(1 2)) ...)`; (2) add code for proper lists: `(check-expect (deep-map add1 '((1))) ...)`; (3) add `lst` not a proper list cases: `(check-expect (deep-map add1 (cons 1 2)) ...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...supposed to take a function `fn` and list `lst`, and applies fn (recursively) to every element of lst,
> *returning a list of the same shape as the original*. `lst` does not need to be a proper list...

To produce the "same shape" list structure, the element which `fn` is applied to must be
a *non-pair*, and `fn` must produce a non-pair result.
(Initially, ignore the condition "lst does not need to be a proper list")

The ***design recipe*** for functions is:

```
1. data definition
2. stub, signature, purpose
3. examples/unit tests
4. template, plan
5. function definition, testing
```

Start with the standard `list` ***data definition*** :

```
LoE (List of Elements) is _one of_:
 - empty
 - (Cons Elt LoE)
```

***Stub*** with ***signature*** and ***purpose***, first ***example/test*** :

```
#lang racket
(require test-engine/racket-tests)

(define (deep-map fn loe) ;; (Elt -> Elt) empty|(Cons Elt LoE) -> empty|(Cons Elt LoE)
  ;; produce list with fn applied to elements of loe
  empty)

(check-expect (deep-map add1 '()) '())

(test)
```

Add more examples, and the basic ***template*** for processing a list:

```
(check-expect (deep-map add1 '(1)) '(2))
(check-expect (deep-map add1 '(1 2)) '(2 3))

(define (process-lox lox) ;; empty|(Cons X LoX) -> ...
  ;; produce result from lox _using natural recursion_
  (cond
    [(empty? lox) ... ]
    [(cons? lox) ... (car lox) ... (process-lox (cdr lox)) ]))
```

Using the stub and examples, substitute names and replace placeholders in template to get the ***function definition*** :

```
(define (deep-map fn loe) ;; (Elt -> Elt) Empty|(Cons Elt LoE) -> Empty|(Cons Elt LoE)
  ;; produce list with fn applied to elements of loe
  (cond
    [(empty? loe) empty ]
    [(cons? loe) (cons (fn (car loe)) (deep-map fn (cdr loe))) ]))
```

This function definition echoes the data definition ("one of" -> `cond`, "Cons" -> `cons` etc).

Now for a "deep" list structure, one can start with extended data definition and more examples:

```
Deep is one of:
- empty
- (Cons Elt Deep)
- (Cons Deep Deep)
where Elt is (And (Not Empty) (Not (Cons ...)))

(check-expect [deep-map add1 '( () )] '( () ) )
(check-expect [deep-map add1 '( (1) )] '( (2) ) )
(check-expect [deep-map add1 '( ((1)) 2 )] '( ((2)) 3 ) )
```

and one can just translate the data definition directly to a function definition as before:

```
(define (deep-map fn deep) ;; (Elt -> Elt) Empty|(Cons Elt Deep)|(Cons Deep Deep) -> Empty|(Cons Elt Deep)|(Cons Deep Deep)
  ;; produce same list structure with fn applied to elements of deep
  (cond
    [(empty? deep) empty ]
    [(and (not (empty? (car deep))) (not (cons? (car deep))))  ;; (Cons Elt Deep)
     (cons (fn (car deep)) (deep-map fn (cdr deep))) ]
    [else (cons (deep-map fn (car deep))                       ;; (Cons Deep Deep)
                (deep-map fn (cdr deep))) ]))
```

Now to add the "lst does not need to be a proper list" condition, repeat the process:

```
Deep is one of:
- Empty
- (Cons Elt Elt)
- (Cons Elt Deep)
- (Cons Deep Elt)
- (Cons Deep Deep)
where Elt is (And (Not Empty) (Not (Cons ...)))

(check-expect (deep-map add1 (cons 1 2))   (cons 2 3))
(check-expect (deep-map add1 (cons '() 2)) (cons '() 3))

(define l1-2 '((1) . 2))
(check-expect (deep-map add1 l1-2)  '((2) . 3))
(check-expect (equal? (deep-map sub1 (deep-map add1 l1-2)) l1-2) #t)
(check-expect (eq?    (deep-map sub1 (deep-map add1 l1-2)) l1-2) #f)

(define (deep-map fn deep) ;; (Elt -> Elt) Empty|(Cons Elt Elt)|... -> Empty|(Cons Elt Elt)|...
  ;; produce same list structure with fn applied to elements of deep
  (define (Elt? x)
    (and (not (empty? x)) (not (cons? x))))
  (cond
    [(empty? deep)  empty ]
    [(and (Elt? (car deep)) (Elt? (cdr deep)))          ;; (Cons Elt Elt)
     (cons (fn (car deep)) (fn (cdr deep))) ]
    [(Elt? (car deep))                                  ;; (Cons Elt Deep)
     (cons (fn (car deep)) (deep-map fn (cdr deep))) ]
    [(Elt? (cdr deep))                                  ;; (Cons Deep Elt)
     (cons (deep-map fn (car deep)) (fn (cdr deep))) ]
    [else                                               ;; (Cons Deep Deep)
     (cons (deep-map fn (car deep)) (deep-map fn (cdr deep))) ]))
```

This version can be simplified [Note 1]:

```
(define (deep-map fn deep) ;; (Elt -> Elt) Empty|(Cons Elt Elt)|... -> Empty|(Cons Elt Elt)|...
  ;; produce same list structure with fn applied to elements of deep
  (define (Elt? x)
    (and (not (empty? x)) (not (cons? x))))
  (cond
    [(empty? deep) empty ]
    [else (cons
           (cond
             [(Elt? (car deep)) (fn (car deep)) ]
             [else (deep-map fn (car deep)) ])
           (cond
             [(Elt? (cdr deep)) (fn (cdr deep)) ]
             [else (deep-map fn (cdr deep)) ])) ]))
```

This function maps lists that can be read as normal s-expressions, but Scheme (and Racket) lists can contain "circular" references:

```
(define ph (make-placeholder #f))

(define ^2
  (let ([x (list ph 2)])
    (placeholder-set! ph x)
    (make-reader-graph x)))
```

`^2` is a (proper) list, which can be `map`ped:

```
(list? ^2)  => #t
(length ^2) => 2
(map number? ^2) => '(#f #t)
```

and `deep-map` of such lists is well defined.

To derive a `deep-map` for these structures, data definition, signature, and purpose are as before;
the plan is to record argument pairs with corresponding result pair in a `mapping` association list;
the function definition is derived from the previous `deep-map` by weaving in code to do this.

```
(require racket/unsafe/ops)

(define mapping empty)

(define (deep-map fn deep) ;; (Elt -> Elt) Empty|(Cons Elt Elt)|... -> Empty|(Cons Elt Elt)|...
  ;; produce same list structure with fn applied to elements of deep
  (define (Elt? x)
    (and (not (empty? x)) (not (cons? x))))
  (cond
    [(empty? deep) empty ]
    [(assq deep mapping) => cdr ]
    [else
     (let ([new-pair (cons #f #f)])
       (set! mapping (cons (cons deep new-pair) mapping))
       (unsafe-set-immutable-car!
        new-pair
        (cond
          [(assq (car deep) mapping) => cdr ]
          [(Elt? (car deep)) (fn (car deep)) ]
          [else (deep-map fn (car deep)) ]))
       (unsafe-set-immutable-cdr!
        new-pair
        (cond
          [(assq (cdr deep) mapping) => cdr ]
          [(Elt? (cdr deep)) (fn (cdr deep)) ]
          [else (deep-map fn (cdr deep)) ]))
       new-pair)]))

(define |0='(1 . #0#)|
  (let ([x (cons 1 ph)])
    (placeholder-set! ph x)
    (make-reader-graph x)))
(check-expect      (deep-map values |0='(1 . #0#)|) |0='(1 . #0#)|)
(check-expect (eq? (deep-map values |0='(1 . #0#)|) |0='(1 . #0#)|) #f)

(define |0='(1 2 #0#)|
  (let ([x (list 1 2 ph)])
    (placeholder-set! ph x)
    (make-reader-graph x)))
(check-expect (deep-map values |0='(1 2 #0#)|) |0='(1 2 #0#)|)

(define |0='(#0# . 2)|
  (let ([x (cons ph 2)])
    (placeholder-set! ph x)
    (make-reader-graph x)))
(check-expect (deep-map values |0='(#0# . 2)|)   |0='(#0# . 2)|)

(define |0='(#0# 2)|
  (let ([x (list ph 2)])
    (placeholder-set! ph x)
    (make-reader-graph x)))
(check-expect (deep-map values |0='(#0# 2)|)     |0='(#0# 2)|)

(define |0='(#0# . #0#)|
  (let* ([ph2 (make-placeholder #f)]
         [x (cons ph ph2)])
    (placeholder-set! ph x)
    (placeholder-set! ph2 x)
    (make-reader-graph x)))
(check-expect (deep-map add1 |0='(#0# . #0#)|) |0='(#0# . #0#)|)

(define |0='(#1=(#0#) . #1#)|
  (let* ([ph2 (make-placeholder #f)]
         [x (list ph ph2)])
    (placeholder-set! ph (cdr x))
    (placeholder-set! ph2 x)
    (make-reader-graph x)))
(check-expect (deep-map add1 |0='(#1=(#0#) . #1#)|) |0='(#1=(#0#) . #1#)|)
```

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 8.6 [cs].
Language: racket, with debugging; memory limit: 128 MB.
All 18 tests passed!
>
```

[Note 1]:
The further simplification:

```
(define (deep-map fn deep) ;; (Elt -> Elt) Empty|(Cons Elt Elt)|... -> Empty|(Cons Elt Elt)|...
  ;; produce same list structure with fn applied to elements of deep
  (cond
    [(empty? deep) empty ]
    [else (cons
           (if (list? (car deep))
               (deep-map fn (car deep))
               (fn (car deep)))
           (if (list? (cdr deep))
               (deep-map fn (cdr deep))
               (fn (cdr deep)))) ]))
```

may be what is expected as a solution to an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it `map**` following a tradition in lisp languages.
(The `map*` is the generalization of `map` to nested lists - and we could think `map**` as the generalization of `map` to any cons-es - thus a further generalization from `map*`).
@mnemenaut's simplified function uses some congenious ideas (e.g. to use `cons` in the `else` branch) but is simply not correct. He fails to discriminate the `empty?` case and to generalize the `list?` to a `cons?`. I therefore correct-simplify it further to:

```
;; apply fn on x when it is an atom, if it is '() return '()
;; otherwise map** fn further on it.
(define (%map** fn x)
  (cond ((empty? x) '()) 
        ((cons? x) (map** fn x))
        (else (fn x))))

;; apply `fn` on atom-level of each part of the cons.
(define (map** fn nl (acc '()))
  (cond ((empty? nl) '())
        (else (cons (%map** (car nl))
                    (%map** fn (cdr nl))))))
```